# Trying to extract an amount of numbers from a list in a range in python 3 using user input as starting point

Tags: python

```
x = input("How many numbers, between two and six?  ")
print("You have selected, " + x + " numbers!")
import random     # I would like to only print out the amount of numbers entered in the first line!!!
numbers = list(range(1,48))   # So if a user types six they get six random numbers and so on.
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: x = input("How many numbers, between two and six?  ")
print("You have selected, " + x + " numbers!")
import random     # I would like to only print out the amount of numbers entered in the first line!!!
numbers = list(range(1,48))   # So if a user types six they get six random numbers and so on.
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)

Comment: are you about `print(numbers[:x]) ?

Comment: Will try that now thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you can explain it a bit more?

Comment: Nope. Type error on line 6.slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: add before `x = int(x)` - input returns string

Comment: If the user types a number into the input on line one. The code pulls that amount of random numbers from that range and prints them. So it changes based on the user input. I am struggling. Could be way off.

Comment: It's a better way `numbers = [random.randint(1, 48) for i in range(int(x))]`

Comment: In your code what a result do you expect if a user input 50 ?

Comment: Specified 2 and 6 numbers but will code in an else or if statement to manage erroneous entries. I will be back.

Comment: @splash58 By using this list comprehension you may get the same number several times, I do not think he wants this or he wouldn't have used a shuffled list(range())

Comment: @ImranD ramdom generator in python is so unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling the list you can just pick x numbers from it;

```py
for i in range(0,x):
    print(i)
```

This does of course assume the input is a number, and you've set the input as an integer with `x = int(input("text"))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
x = input("How many numbers, between two and six?  ")
print("You have selected, " + x + " numbers!")
numbers = list(range(1,48))
print([random.choice(numbers) for x in range(int(x))])
```

`random.choice(numbers)` is a function that takes a argument that must be list and give you any random number as return value, the for loop is used to run `random.choice()` function for range defined by x. suppose user enter the value 2 so we have `x=2` then our for loop will run 2 times and we have 2 random value as output from our `numbers` list.

Comment: you can give input number as small or large as you want like 1,2 or even 99 or more this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    for x in range(int(x)):
        print(random.randint(1, 48))
```

it will work you can also append into the list if you want.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
import random

x = input("How many numbers, between two and six?  ")
print("You have selected, " + x + " numbers!")
li = [random.random() for x in range(int(x))]
print(li)
```